# Breakpointing/debugging other user processes from c/c++ on unix

Tags: c++, c, macos, unix, gdb

As the headline says, I'm looking for a way to set breakpoints on other processes from within a c/c++ application, ideally via some existing library, and react when those breakpoints are triggered (without interrupting the host process).

The end goal is a small and very general scripting engine, portable across unices, for user land processes.

So, does anyone have ideas on how this could be achieved, or heard about similar projects or functionality? If my general approach is off I'd gladly take feedback on how to achieve this in another way.

**EDIT:** In keeping with SO standards, the specific question is whether breakpoints/process interaction is available through libraries or unix syscalls in c/c++.

Comment: you can use gdb. it can be integrated, that's what most of the IDEs do..

Comment: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_211.html

Comment: Thanks for your help! For the interested I'm also looking into [ptrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace) for similar functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the specific question is whether breakpoints/process interaction is available through libraries or unix syscalls in c/c++.

Yes: `ptrace` is the only portable Unix system call for this.

You will quickly discover that to do *anything* useful with it, you'll have to write a *ton* of code.

I expect you'll have to implement ~50% of GDB before you have anything scriptable and generally useful, so a better approach might be to *start* with GDB, and use its built-in python scripting instead.

There are also platform-specific improvements over `ptrace`, (Solaris implements `ptrace` in terms of `/procfs`; Linux has `utrace`, though it appears to be stillborn).

You may also look at Linux-specific `frysk` for ideas.

Comment: The tip on `frysk`was great - ty!